# Find top scoring comment on Reddit in may 2015

Tags: php, reddit

I want to write a page in PHP (essentially) that would be able to tell me the top scoring comment for the month of may 2015, or the year 2015.  How do I go about doing this?

I've found this PHP api:

https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk

But it just seems to show how to log in a post comments etc.  I want to query the Database, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look at the reddit api docs http://www.reddit.com/dev/api it has all information about what information you can access from reddit. That library/package only provides a front to the reddit API.

You could use [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or a similar to make your requests to the API, if you cannot find a suitable reddit client-library.

Answer (score 0):

> But it just seems to show how to log in a post comments etc. I want to query the Database, how do I go about doing that?

You don't.  HTTP APIs generally don't allow arbitrary queries of that kind, and reddit in particular does not for performance reasons.

The only place I can think of that sorts individual comments by `top` is the userpage, and building a list of millions of users and trying to scrape through their userpages to gather top comments (and place them into monthly buckets) will probably take much longer than you'd like.